# AWS websocket in Beanstalk through API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

I have an application using Websockets. It is already deployed on AWS using beanstalk.
I want to "serve it" via API Gateway, so i configured my beanstalk env with a network load balancer and added a vpc link.
I'm not sure on which one to pick among: VPC link for REST APIs or VPC link for HTTP APIs? will the ws connection be feasible with such stack? since ws protocol handshake is done via http ?